# Integral of exponential and square root

Tags: definite-integrals, moment-generating-functions

I am trying to find the moment generating function for a random variable with the probability distribution of
$$
f_X(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2π}\sqrt{4-x^2},& -2\le x\le 2 \\
\\
0, &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

For the moment generating function I have
$$
M(t) = E[e^{tx}]=\int_{-2}^{2}e^{tx}\frac{1}{2π}\sqrt{4-x^2}\ dx\\
=\frac{1}{2π}\int_{-2}^{2}e^{tx}\sqrt{4-x^2}\ dx
$$

But I am having trouble trying to integrate this.

I have tried to find the expectation $E[X]$, $E[X^2]$, ... individually and it turns out the expectation is equal to $0$ when $n$ is even for the $n^{th}$ moment, so I am assuming the integral would contain a trigonometric function in it. Can somebody help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this integral has a solution in terms of primary functions. You can try using wolframalpha to see what the solution looks like. See here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration+e%5E%28tx%29+sqrt%284-x%5E2%29+from+-2+to+2

Answer (score 1):

$$M(t) = E[e^{tx}]=
\frac{1}{2π}\int_{-2}^{2}e^{tx}\sqrt{4-x^2}\ dx=\frac 2 \pi\int_{-1}^{1} e^{2 t y}\sqrt{1-y^2}=\frac{I_1(2 t)}{t}$$ where appears  the modified Bessel function of the first kind.